# Jmeter - getting 401 unauthorized error after login

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have to record a large test plan including 4 transactional controllers and response assertions for the UI side but at the time of login there is token generated and I am doing correlation manually.

I have used the regular expression extractor to extract the token from my login response but it gives the following error:

```
org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: (?<=("|')token("|'):("|'))(.*?)("|')(=?) Sequence (?<...) not recognized.
```

Please guide me also how can [image: testplan]I pass this TOKEN on the further request as each request has its own header manager. How I can pass THIS TOKEN OVER 4 TRANSACTIONAL CONTROLLER. I am adding my test plan for reference. Please guide me on a suitable process to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception clearly states that  **Sequence (?<...)** not recognized

As per jmeter documentation https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html,
Lookbehind expression (?<=) is not supported.

[image]

So use:

```
("|')token("|'):("|')(.*?)("|')
```

Here we have 5 groups, the actual token is in the 4th group and to get just the token value set template field as: $4$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works

Comment: @coder_m please accept the answer and upvote. Just click up arrow and tick

Comment: Can you bit help me out t, how do I pass this extracted token in further requests as it is testing of UI side and there are a lot of HTTP requests recorded with their header manager so I have to pass this request in all subsequent requests and by adding just one header manager over the controller does not do the work. it gives 401 unathorized

Comment: http://blogs.quovantis.com/jmeter-authorization-with-dynamic-access-token/

Comment: See if this help , I am not sure about other answers has haven't worked much on it